# Cannot mock an object inside an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I am trying to nest an object inside another using `FactoryGirl`. I have this

```
# app/models/one.rb
class One < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :two_and_three
end
```

And the second model

```
# app/models/two_and_three.rb
class TwoAndThree < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cast
  belongs_to :one
end
```

I am trying to mock them like this:

```
# spec/factories/one.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :one do
    two_and_three FactoryGirl.build(:TwoAndThree)
  end
end
```

And

```
# spec/factories/two_and_three.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :TwoAndThree do
    cast Faker::Name.name
  end
end
```

I am getting `uninitialized constant TwoAndThree` when I run the test. How do I make FactoryGirl mock an object inside a mocked object?

Comment: Is your second code snippet correct? It shows a class name of `One` instead of `TwoAndThree`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition in `two_and_three.rb` is incorrect. It has `One` instead of `TwoAndThree`, which is why you're getting an uninitialized constant error.  It's auto-loading the file, but the class is not being defined as a result.

Comment: It's actually `TwoAndThree`. Copy paste error on my part, sorry about that. Also, the error is from `two_and_three FactoryGirl.build(:TwoAndThree)` in `one.rb`, according to the stack trace.

Comment: @AbhishekChanda If you're getting that uninitialized constant error and your model name is correct, then the only thing I can think of is that you haven't required `spec_helper` and therefore haven't enabled auto loading.